# How to compare dates in xpath for selecting nodes

Tags: xml, xpath

I want to get nodes based on condition given in xpath for date comparison. How I can do that using xpath?

Do i need to use `adjust-dateTime-to-timezone`?

Comment: Can you provide an example of the comparison that you need (e.g. nodes who's value is greater than X, nodes that are between x and y, etc.)?  Dates are much easier in XPath 2.0.  Can you use 2.0, or do you need a 1.0 solution?

Answer (score 3):

**XPath 2.0 has a [number of date/time functions and operators](http://www.w3.org/TR/xpath-functions/#durations-dates-times) to help processing dates.**

Assume that you had an XML document like this:

```
<doc>
    <event date="2011-02-05">foo</event>
    <event date="2011-08-01">bar</event>
    <event date="2011-08-20">baz</event>
    <event date="2011-11-07">qux</event>

</doc>
```

and you want to filter the events by `@date` for those in August 2011.

You could use this XPath:

```
/doc/event[xs:date(@date) le xs:date('2011-08-31') and 
                            xs:date(@date) ge xs:date('2011-08-01')]
```

and it would select the `event` elements for `bar` and `baz`.